# What does this lambda expression do and how

Tags: lambda, java-8

I'm learning Java 8 Lambda expressions. I got the basic understanding of Lambda. But I don't understand how following code is working for the code snippet:-

```
return new Quote(quote, 
                     stock.getQuote().getPrice());  // Confusion here.
```

Does this return to the following function which is `.collect(Collectors.toList())` or return from the Lambda completely. Please explain in details how does it work?

```
public List<Quote> getStock(){
    List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
    return quotes
            .stream()
            .map(quote -> {
                Stock stock = getStockPrice(quote);
                return new Quote(quote, stock.getQuote().getPrice()); // Confusion here
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns from the lambda. Remember, a lambda is basically nothing more than an anonymous function.

You could rewrite your code, without Streams, as:

```
public List<Quote> getStock() {
    List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Quote> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String quote : quotes)
    {
        Quote theQuote = myLambda(quote);
        returnList.add(theQuote);
    }
    return returnList;
}

private Quote myLambda(String quote)
{
    Stock stock = getStockPrice(quote);
    return new Quote(quote, stock.getQuote().getPrice());
}
```

The `return` in your version using a lambda and the `return` in my version act in exactly the same way. They return from the function to allow the next quote to be processed.

It's also worth noting that your `getStock` method creates a new empty ArrayList and creates a stream from that list. As such, the resulting `List<Quote>` will always currently be empty.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
.map(quote -> {
       Stock stock = getStockPrice(quote);
       return new Quote(quote,  stock.getQuote().getPrice());
    })
```

takes a `String` as input and returns a `Quote`; it's a `Function<String, Quote>`. You can implement this Function via a class :

```
class FromStringToQuote implements Function<String, Quote> {

      public Quote apply (String quote) ...
```

May be that will make it more clear.

For each element from `quotes` (which are `String`s) you map these to a `Quote` via the lambda expression.

After one is mapped, it is sent to the `Collectors.toList()`; that collects that to a `List`.